# Finding the domain of the function $1 - |x| , [x] - x$

Tags: functions

The problem is

> Consider the function $f(x) =$
>
> i) $1 - |x|$
>
> ii) $[x] - x$
>
> Find domain.

I understand the definition of domain of a function as *it is the set of all possible inputs that will result an output from the function*.

But i am certainly not getting around any values which will make $f(x)$ undefined, as if we were given $\frac1{1-x}$ or $\sqrt{x²+2x-1}$ where we are getting reasons  for $f(x)$ to term it as undefined, like in $1$st case $x$ can not be less than $1$ and in $2$nd case the the whole equation under root cant be just negative!

I suspect there is something more needed to be put into the definition of *domain* . Any clarification would greatly reduce the surmounted stress!

Comment: Precisely for that reason the domain is all real numbers for both. As for the other example you have taken, $f(x)=1/(1-x)$, $x$ can be less than $1$, just not equal to $1$.

Comment: Well, that is where i was pointing to! Where is that value for which 1 - | x | would become undefined ?

Comment: There is no such real value. The book has the wrong answer.

Comment: You are mean to say which i quote" the function 1 - |x| have domain of real number R ?"

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Here is a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/o7nteetfxb) to prove adding and subtraction of 1 from |x| does not change its domain. The domain appears to be all x$\in\Bbb C$ because the absolute value of a complex number is the pythagorean theorem on the real and imaginary part. The only thing that would make this undefined were maybe if x itself was an indeterminate form, x was undefined or complex infinity etc.

Comment: My stress is releived now. Thank you for such an romantic mathematical disscussion ! Pleasure. -- Tyma Gaidash -- Shubham Johri ---programmer365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $f(x)$ is an expression like $1-|x|$ domain will be **all real numbers meaning $x$ is an element of set of all real numbers**. If $x$ is something other than a real number then it will cause the function to be undefined. Definition of the domain is fully correct.

And for an expression like $1/(1-x)$ the domain will be also **all real numbers except them which make $1-x$ result $0$**, and obviously it is $1$, so the domain will be all real numbers except $1$.

Comment: In the book the answer is mentioned for the (i) as R - {-1,1}  , i clearly understood it is the set all R but why substract minus 1? Does 1 - | -1| or 1 - | 1 | is un defined?

Comment: @kunalCh. R is the set of real numbers, you remove 1 from it, if you use - or \ between sets it means removing an elements of one set from the another

Comment: @kunalCh. The book is wrong.